# Pandas: Transform Dataframe into list of Dataframes by adjacent rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Convert this dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
0   '1'   '2'   '3'
1   '1'   '4'   '5'
2   '2'   '6'   '7'
3   '2'   '8'   '9'
4   '1'   '0'   '1'
5   '2'   '2'   '3'
```

into this list of dataframes:

```
    A   B   C
0   '1'   '2'   '3'
1   '1'   '4'   '5'

    A   B   C
2   '2'   '6'   '7'
3   '2'   '8'   '9'

    A   B   C
4   '1'   '0'   '1'

    A   B   C
5   '2'   '2'   '3'
```

such that all adjacent rows of the same A group are together in their own dataframe. I've tried various combinations of groupby and drop_duplicates, but these are not dealing with the contiguous nature of the rows. And diff doesn't like strings.

Comment: `[y for x,y in df.groupby(df.A.diff().ne(0).cumsum())]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
data = StringIO("""

A   B   C
1   2   3
1   4   5
2   6   7
2   8   9
1   0   1
2   2   3

""")
```

Group by the running sum of changes in A not equal to 0:

```
df = pd.read_table(data, delim_whitespace=True)

for x ,y in df.groupby(df.A.astype('category').cat.codes.diff().ne(0).cumsum()):
    print(y)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  4  5
   A  B  C
2  2  6  7
3  2  8  9
   A  B  C
4  1  0  1
   A  B  C
5  2  2  3
```

Comment: What about for string variables?

Comment: If you have strings that could be coerced to numeric I would just do that. But you are right, with strings it is different

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.flatnonzero` to find where diffs are not zero and `numpy.split` split the dataframe.

```
a = df.A.values
lodf = np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(a[:-1] != a[1:]) + 1)

print(*lodf, sep='\n\n')

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  4  5

   A  B  C
2  2  6  7
3  2  8  9

   A  B  C
4  1  0  1

   A  B  C
5  2  2  3
```